# Method signature

Tags: c#

For example:

```
public abstract class A
{}

public class B : A
{}

public class C
{
   public static void DoSth(List<A> a)
   {
   }
}

Main
{
  List<B> muchB = new List<B>;

  C.DoSth(muchB); //Here Compiler tell me that List<B> isnt possible.
}
```

Someone can tell me why this isnt possible? Or what i can do to make it possible?

Comment: List<A> is different from List<B>. You are not passing the correct data type. Remember here the data type is List<T> and not A or B and hence your inheritance rules will not apply.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Oops, I did not realise that ;p

Comment: Make `DoSth` a generic method with `T : A` constraint

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot! I use your solution. At first i changed the type to Array and then used the List.ToArray() Method. But your solution is pretty nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per DanielHilgarth's comment, the data type expected by DoSth is a strongly-typed list.  By adding a type constraint to DoSth, you can achieve what you want.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<B> muchB = new List<B>();
    C.DoSth<B>(muchB);
}

public abstract class A {}

public class B : A {}

public class C 
{
    public static void DoSth<T>(List<T> a) where T : A { }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't, because of the Covariance problem mentioned in the comments.  What if `DoSth` did this:

```
public class A2 : A
{
}

public static void DoSth(List<A> a)
{
     a.Add(new A2()); // but a is a List<B>!!!
}
```

One option would be to make `DoSth` generic with a type constraint:

```
public static void DoSth<T>(List<T> a) where T : A
{
}
```

Then your code would work because passing in a `List<B>` means you could only add `B`s (or classes derived from `B`).

Comment: Are you mixing up a few A's and B's? Shouldn't it be "where T : A" and "or classes derived from A"?

Comment: @Abbas - oops yes I fixed the type constraint.  However my second statement is correct - if you pass in a `List<B>` you could only add `B`s - you could not add `A`s.

Comment: Yes, but I tought you meant that you could not pass a List<A> to the DoSth-method. This is still possible, right?

Comment: @Abbas Sure - then everything gets treated as an `A`.  The original example is passing in a `List<B>` so that was the basis for my comment.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. And your comment is absolutely correct and clear to me now. ;)